# how to run a go get command with certain environment values?

Tags: windows, go, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, goproxy

I want to run a go get command when `GOPROXY='direct'`, I've tried to run this command using the VS code terminal:

```
GOPROXY='direct' go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
GOPROXY=direct : The term 'GOPROXY=direct' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ GOPROXY='direct' go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (GOPROXY=direct:String) [], CommandNotFoundEx  
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I've also tried:

```
go env set GOPROXY='direct'
```

but when I run `go env` command the `GOPROXY` value is still like this `GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct`
and I also tried to define a GOPROXY variable in the windows environment variable and giving it the value of `direct` but it also failed to do the job.

Comment: Would you send the output of  'go env' command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your VSCode terminal is a `bash` one, not a CMD or Powershell.

In a CMD or Powershell, the syntax `var=xxx cmd` would not be correctly interpreted as: set a variable and execute a command inheriting its environment variables, including the one set.